# Flask Sessions seem to be not working, can someone help me?

Tags: python, flask, session, stripe-payments

So I have been working on Flask and Stripe for a week now, and I have made some progress(I wanna thank stack overflow). I really need help with sessions though. I keep receiving a KeyError when using Flask not sure why. I have added a comment to each piece of code im referring to.

The comment is: #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO

Any help would be appreciated, I assume this might be due to the conflicting variable names that stripe uses and flask uses(since they both use session) but wouldn't I get an error for that specifically? Instead I just get a KeyError.

Thank you.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, abort, session
import random
import subprocess
import stripe

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'PUBLIC KEY'
app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET KEY'

stripe.api_key = app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

app.secret_key="SECRETFORSESSIONS"

@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
       location = request.form["location"]  #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
       industry = request.form["industry"]  #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
       session['location'] = location             #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
       session['industry'] = industry             #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
       return render_template("home.html")
    else:
       return render_template("home.html")
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/initialpay')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/stripe_pay')
def stripe_pay():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': 'priceofanitem',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('thanks', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('index', _external=True),
    )
    return {
        'checkout_session_id': session['id'], 
        'checkout_public_key': app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
    }

    

@app.route('/thanks')
def thanks():
    return render_template("thanks.html")

@app.route('/stripe_webhook', methods=['POST'])
def stripe_webhook():
    print('WEBHOOK CALLED')
    if request.content_length > 1024 * 1024:
        print('REQUEST TOO BIG')
        abort(400)
    payload = request.get_data()
    sig_header = request.environ.get('HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE')
    endpoint_secret = 'ENDPOINT_SECRET'
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        print('INVALID PAYLOAD')
        return {}, 400
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signatures
        print('INVALID SIGNATURE')
        return {}, 400

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        print(session)
        line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session['id'], limit=1)
        print(line_items['data'][0]['description'])
        location = session["location"]        #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
        industry = session["industry"]        #THIS IS THE CODE IM REFERRING TOO
        print(location)
        print(industry)
        emaildata = session.customer_details.email
        sessionParam = str(random.randint(10000, 90000))
        if checkout_session.payment_status == 'paid':
            #DO TASKS
        


    return {}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Here is the error:

```
[2022-11-05 07:11:51,884] ERROR in app: Exception on /stripe_webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/mainapp/__init__.py", line 85, in stripe_webhook
    location = s["location"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'location'
```

Comment: Please, include the full traceback you get. Do you get KeyErrr in `request.form` (in `home()` or in `s` (in `stripe_webhook()`). The title suggest it i `s`, the comments - it may be the `request.form`

Comment: Show the error first

Comment: @buran I have edited the post and added the full error.

Comment: @Mehmaam I have edited the post and added the full error

Comment: Session is used to keep track of a customer navigating between parts of your app/website. However, webhook is the asynchronous request to your server from Stripe and it doesn't have information about customer's session.

Comment: @yuting webhook confirms if a checkout.session is complete, is their a way I can verify this outside of stripe_webhook, if so, where? I just need to confirm the checkout session is complete. I have also tried updating the json response creating by checkout session but to no avail.

Comment: Using webhook is recommended to get payment outcome of a Checkout Session. It's possible to store additional information on a Checkout Session under [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata) parameter in key-value pair when creating a Checkout Session. Metadata will also be present as part of `checkout.session.completed` event that you can use to retrieve these information.